# How do I make a line stretch before line break?

Tags: line-breaking

I want to break before the equation to ensure it doesn't end up on two lines:

```
Words words words words words words words words words words words words words words
words words words words words words words words \\$equation = equation$.
```

However, I don't want the resulting "right-indent" on the second line:

[image]

How do I make the line stretch?

Comment: My understanding is that in a case like this, LaTeX has considered how it would look with the space on the right (bad) and how it would look with the words stretched out (more bad) and gone for the lesser evil; in most cases LaTeX's judgements of this type are sound and it's risky to play around with the settings too much.

Comment: If you want the equation to take up its own line, you probably want it in a display environment (`\[ ... \]` or similar), rather than just forcing a line-break within a paragraph of text.

Comment: You should use `=\nolinebreak` and use your judgment when the paragraph turns out difficult to typeset. A long formula might be displayed, for instance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use `=\nolinebreak`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{indentfirst}

\begin{document}

\subsubsection*{Bad, with \texttt{\string\\}}

Words words words words words words words words words words words words words words
words words words words words words words words \\$equation = equation$.

\subsubsection*{Slightly better, with \texttt{\string\linebreak}}

Words words words words words words words words words words words words words words
words words words words words words words words \linebreak $equation = equation$.

\subsubsection*{Even better, with \texttt{\string\nolinebreak}}

Words words words words words words words words words words words words words words
words words words words words words words words $equation =\nolinebreak equation$.

\subsubsection*{Even better, with \texttt{\string\nolinebreak}}

\begin{sloppypar}
Words words words words words words words words words words words words words words
words words words words words words words words $equation =\nolinebreak equation$.
\end{sloppypar}

\end{document}
```

[image]

You might object that `=\nolinebreak` doesn't achieve the result. Actually it does! You *may* sometimes get an overfull line and in this case you can exercise your judgment in order to fix the typesetting:

1. change wording,
2. display the equation,
3. accept the line break after `=`, or
4. use `sloppypar` as a last resort as in the fourth example.

Can you see a difference between the second and fourth examples? Not in this case, actually, but changing the class might show one.

This is the output with `amsart`, for instance.

[image]

Can you spot the difference now?

I'm not saying you *must* use `sloppypar`. It should be the last resort; rewording is usually the best strategy and chances are that no action is required if the equation is not too wide and the paragraph is long enough.

Comment: Thanks. With no manual line break at all, the first line in my paragraph breaks between `smallest` and `integer`. With `\linebreak` LaTex actively worsens the situation with `smallest in-` `teger`. With `sloppypar` I get `small-` `est integer`, which mitigates the sparseness of the broken line.

Comment: Also, `\nolinebreak` can be replaced by curly brackets: `${equation = equation}$`

Comment: New problem: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/600331/sloppypar-adds-vertical-spacing-when-next-to-equations

Answer (score 2):

If you *really* want that then use `\linebreak` not `\\`

Comment: It seems like LaTex likes to move around words so that the line with `\linebreak` is even more sparse than it has to be, so it's necessary to use `\linebreak` on the previous line as well.