# sloppypar adds vertical spacing when next to equations

Tags: line-breaking, sloppy

```
paragraph 1
\begin{equation*}
    equation 1
\end{equation*}
paragraph 2

paragraph 3
\begin{equation*}
    equation 2
\end{equation*}
paragraph 4

paragraph 5
```

There's an inline equation in paragraph 4 which I keep on one line by preceding it with `\linebreak`. However, I have found out that `sloppypar`, along with surrounding the equation in brackets, is preferable as it selects better line breaks, i.e. `\begin{sloppypar} paragraph 4 \end{sloppypar}` and `${a=b}$`. The problem is that this increases the vertical spacing between equation 2 and paragraph 4 (but not to paragraph 5). Similarly, enclosing paragraph 3 in `sloppypar` increases the spacing to equation 2 (but not to paragraph 2).

By starting paragraph 4 with `\sloppy` instead, the spacing to equation 2 is not increased, but the spacing between equation 1 and paragraphs 1 and 2 is increased; perhaps it makes the whole document sloppy?

How do I make the paragraph sloppy without such adverse effects?

Edit: here's code to reproduce the `sloppypar` issue.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,final]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\setlength\parindent{0pt}
\setlength{\parskip}{10pt}

\begin{document}
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
    
    Cras arcu arcu, volutpat sed rhoncus porttitor, tincidunt at eros. Praesent at leo non arcu rutrum maximus in ut nibh. Ut rutrum efficitur tincidunt. Etiam fermentum nunc vitae sapien mattis cursus. Proin venenatis nulla velit, at dictum risus commodo non. Pellentesque semper
    \begin{equation*}
        \frac{lorem}{ipsum} = dolor\frac{sit}{amet}
    \end{equation*}
    Donec malesuada mollis mauris id fermentum. Vivamus arcu felis \linebreak $lorem = ipsum+dolor$.
    
    Vestibulum ornare euismod est a rutrum. In dictum elit dapibus velit consequat, vitae accumsan purus fermentum. Morbi aliquam, purus eget euismod interdum, arcu mi molestie turpis, ut sodales urna dolor pharetra dui.
\end{document}
```

Compare to `\begin{sloppypar}Donec malesuada mollis mauris id fermentum. Vivamus arcu felis ${lorem = ipsum+dolor}$.\end{sloppypar}`.

Comment: I recommended to use `sloppypar` as a *last resort*. Don't worry about such problems until your document is in final form as regards to the text. Anyway, debugging the issue needs code that reproduces it.

Comment: as egreg says sloppypar is rather intrusive, Also it is very tricky ti put a display equation in a group without adversley affecting the spacing why "urrounding the equation in brackets"??  but you should provide an example it would be hard to guess your input or the effect that has on the output from your description.

Comment: @egreg There's code now.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle The brackets ensure that the equation stays on one line instead of being broken up at the equals sign.

Comment: oh I thought you meant you put braces around `\begin{equation}..\end{equation}`  but you mean you put the braces _inside_ inline math, there are better ways of stopping line breaking, I'll link to an answer. You have added an example but it is very hard to give sensible improvements to the line breaking if the text and math just has fake latin

Comment: @DavidCarlisle For this particular example, using `\linebreak` works just fine. I'm looking for a general solution - something that does the job of `sloppypar` but without the extra vertical space.

Comment: sloppypar does nothing more then `{\par\sloppy text \par}`, and the first `\par` introduce the spacing, you would get it too with an empty line after your equation. There is no general solution for your problem. You should decide in such cases if you accept bad line breaking, or a break in the math, or if you can change the wording of the sentence.